# How to get `docker run` full arguments?

Tags: docker

For example, I run a docker by `docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 19000:9000 -p 19002:9002 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=123 --link sonarqube-mysql:mysql`.

Then I lost my shell command history, but I want to know all my arguments.
How can I get them? (I need the arguments to copy/move/restart container)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course `docker inspect` is the way to go, but if you just want to "reconstruct" the docker run command, you have

https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod

it says

`Reverse engineer a docker run command from an existing container (via docker inspect).`

Comment: This works pretty well, though I've already ran into cases where rekcod is quite wrong. It's a good pointer in the right direction. But you will definitely want to filter out some of the extraneous flags at a minimum.

Comment: Log a PR on the rekcod site so it will be fixed

Answer (score 3):

`docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME` gives you that information.

Check `docker inspect` reference to see all available options: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/

Comment: Thanks, I tried inspect before, but there are so many data, it's hard to find out which is default value, which is not.